# UWP Sub certificates Manifest Designer could not import the certficate

Tags: c#, uwp, certificate

With Powershell and New-SelfSignedCertificate cmdlet I create a Root certificate and a Sub certificate which uses the root certificate (for Code signing) as signer (-Signer).
I choose the Sub certificate in a VS2017 UWP App from the Package.appxmanifest. Both certificates is installed in the trusted root authority.
But I always get the error message 
"Manifest Designer could not import the certificate. The certificate you selected is not valid".

The question is why?

If I do not sign (remove -Signer) the Sub certificate, with the root certificate then it works.
It seems I can not use a Sub certificate.
I took care that the `BasicConstrains` is

> "TextExtension = '2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3' , '2.5.29.19 =
>   {text}Subject Type:End Entity'"

Comment: Can you explain us about why a sub certificate is requested here? Any specific reason?

Comment: I want to build a trusted certificate chain for different propose. To sign different Software application, but from the same root certificate. Root-SubCA1-SubCA2.

Comment: In the meanwhile I found a solution for my problem. I had to change the   parameters of the certificates.   
**Root Certificate**
 `CertStoreLocation = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
  KeyUsage = 'CertSign'
  Type = 'Custom'
  TextExtension = '2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3' , '2.5.29.19 = {text}ca=true&pathlength=1'
  Subject = "dummy”` 
**Sub Certificate** 
 `CertStoreLocation = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
  Type = 'CodeSigningCert'
  TextExtension = '2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3' , '2.5.29.19 = {text}Subject Type:End Entity'
  Subject = "dummy"
  Signer=$rootcert`